# Appropriateness of usage of the phrases "and such forth", and "so hence forth"

Tags: phrase-requests, word-usage, phrase-usage

I have a colleague who frequently uses the phrases,

"and such forth" and "so hence forth" in conversations with clients.

I find particularly the use of "and such forth" to be nonsensical and inappropriate, however need some justification for my profound dislike of the usage. I'm thinking my dislike of "so hence forth" is more to do with my dislike of the person themselves, but am seeking the appropriate way (if any) to use these phrases in conversation.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

"And such forth" is incorrect.  The proper idiom is "and so forth," or "and so on."

"Hence forth," usually spelled as one word these days, means "from now on."  Whether your colleague is using the phrase correctly in context, you would know better than I, but at least it's correct English.  It's a rather formal word, however, and not one likely to be used in colloquial speech.

Comment: Was going to post my own answer, but this one covers it admirably.  The co-worker is confused and spouting embarrasing nonsense.

Comment: I might argue that "so hence forth" is redundant unless the "so" is a conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

An English speaker would probably understand the phrase "suchforth", even though it would sound fairly strange. "Etc", "and so on", and "so forth" would be more natural.